Understanding symmetry in a double integral
I was reading about the solution of the integral $$\int_0^1\int^1_0 \frac {\arctan(x-y)} {x-y}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy $$
And the first step is to convert that integral into $$2\int_0^1\int^1_0 \frac {\arctan(x-xy)} {1-y}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy  $$
by symmetry. I didn't understand how is that done.

Not sure about symmetry, but substituting $y\to xy$ in the first expression yields matching integrands, and then it's a question of showing$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x-xy)}{1-y},dy,dx=\int_0^1\int_1^\tfrac1x\frac{\arctan(x-xy)}{1-y},dy,dx$$

The unit square can be integrated over in this other manner:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1=\int_0^1\int_0^x+\int_0^1\int_x^1$$
In your case,
$$\int_0^1\int_0^x\frac{\arctan(x-y)}{x-y}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx+\int_0^1\int_x^1\frac{\arctan(x-y)}{x-y}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$
If we now apply Fubini to the $2^{\text{nd}}$ integral you get
$$\int_0^1\int_0^x\frac{\arctan(x-y)}{x-y}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx+\int_0^1\int_0^y\frac{\arctan(x-y)}{x-y}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$
Since $x$ and $y$ are dummy variables you can do $x\leftrightarrow y$ and get
$$\int_0^1\int_0^x\frac{\arctan(x-y)}{x-y}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx+\int_0^1\int_0^x\frac{\arctan(y-x)}{y-x}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$
which is just
$$2\int_0^1\int_0^x\frac{\arctan(x-y)}{x-y}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$
Now you just make the substitution $z=\frac{y}{x}$ getting in turn
$$2\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x-xz)}{x-zx}x\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dx\overset{z=y\text{ dummy}}{=}2\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x-xy)}{1-y}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$

@HomamHassn you can accept the answer if it solves your problems

What is a dummy variable? Why x is equivalent to y?

@TheSapient When you have a definite integral, the variable of integration and in the function doesn't really matter: $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\int_0^1 f(y)dy=\int_0^1 f(\xi)d\xi$.  The variable is almost a placeholder, or dummy.  In that case, if you switch every occurrence of the variable, then you've not changed anything.  Another way to look at it is that you're doing the integral substitutions (1) $x\to z$, (2) $y\to x$, and then (3) $z\to y$.

Let $f(t)$ be an even function on $[-1,1].$  The integral $$I=\int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1f(x-y)\,dy\,dx$$ can be split into the sum of  two integrals $I_1$ and $I_2$ over the regions $y<x$ and $x<y.$ These integrals are equal to each other due to the symmetry of $f(t).$ Hence $$I=I_1+I_2=2I_1= \int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^xf(x-y)\,dy\,dx \underset{y=xu}{=}\int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1xf(x-xu)\,du\,dx$$
